# How to reference a sublayer by name in an Illustrator script?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, layers, illustrator-scripting

How can one reference a sublayer in functions like `setLayerVisibility`, that accept layer names as arguments?

I tried

```
setLayerVisibility("MyLayerName.MySublayerName", true)
```

, but that was ineffective.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the function may not be set up to look for sublayers, even if you pass the correct sublayer name. If it is, you can do something like...

```
var myLayer = app.activeDocument.layers["myLayerName"];
var mySublayer = myLayer.layers["mySublayerName"];

alert(mySublayer.name);
```

Comment: ”may not be set up […]” Well, yes, this script works indeed! It *does* alert the correct sublayer name.